# Fabric.js: parts of Line not rendered after updating its dimensions programmatically

Tags: width, fabricjs

I draw a line, then try to change it, leaving the same starting point with `x1`(left) and `x1`(top) and moving the endpoint by changing the line's `width` (`x2-x1` - negative when moved left of originating point) and `height` (determined by `y2-y1`).

The line is drawn repeatedly with positive `width` value but 90% of the time it has gaps in the stroke as if the line is not fully stretched from border to border.

Below I define the line, it works well and connects my 2 points. Then, I modify the line when one of the flow objects is moved. When I move the bottom object to the right (positive width), it works fine, when I move to the left (negative width) the line does not reach its borders. The line has `borders: true` so I can see that the borders are lined up perfectly with the flow objects they are trying to connect (visible in the images).

```
//[startleft, starttop, endleft, endtop] 
canvas.add(new fabric.Line(
  [globalConnect[0], globalConnect[1], globalConnect[2], globalConnect[3]], {
      stroke:'black', 
      strokeWidth:3,  
      lockScalingX:true, 
      lockScalingY:true, 
      lockRotation:true, 
      hasControls:true, 
      hasBorders:true, 
      lockMovementX:true, 
      lockMovementY:true
    })
);


canvas.item(tempObjectIdx + 1).left = tempX1;
canvas.item(tempObjectIdx + 1).top = tempY1;
canvas.item(tempObjectIdx + 1).width = tempX2-tempX1;
canvas.item(tempObjectIdx + 1).height = tempY2-tempY1;
```

Example of the line when it's not fully drawn: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et2Qg.png)

Example of what line looks like with positive width or negative width when it works fine: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoqqs.png)

Anybody having similar problems with negative widths when redrawing a line? Is there something to do with origination point - or recalculating coordinates, I do redraw canvas after setting these values - works great for positive value, but the line does not span the border box when `width` is negative (I have tried redrawing line from bottom origin with positive width and negative height - no better?)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It would really help if you could share a minimal snippet that illustrates the problem. It's hard to tell exactly what the problem is without some guessing on a reader's part.

Comment: I have updated the code and description in the original message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need the line to connect two points and update it whenever those two points are updated, you only have to set the line's `x1`,`y1` and `x2`,`y2` on each appropriate event. Here's an example where such line is updated when the boxes fire `moving` events:

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c')
const box1 = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'green'
})
const box2 = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 250,
  top: 250,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'red'
})
const box1point = box1.getPointByOrigin('center', 'bottom')
const box2point = box2.getPointByOrigin('center', 'top')
const connector = new fabric.Line(
    [box1point.x, box1point.y, box2point.x, box2point.y],
    {
      stroke: "black",
      strokeWidth: 3,
      lockScalingX: true,
      lockScalingY: true,
      lockRotation: true,
      hasControls: true,
      hasBorders: true,
      lockMovementX: true,
      lockMovementY: true
    }
  )
box1.on('moving', function() {
  const connectPoint = this.getPointByOrigin('center', 'bottom')
  connector.set({
    x1: connectPoint.x,
    y1: connectPoint.y
  })
})
box2.on('moving', function() {
  const connectPoint = this.getPointByOrigin('center', 'top')
  connector.set({
    x2: connectPoint.x,
    y2: connectPoint.y
  })
})
canvas.add(box1, box2, connector)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.3/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='c' width="500" height="400"></canvas>
```